# C11/C++11 Memory Model

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, memory-model, c11

I have two questions:

1. I would like to know if the standards for C++11 and C11 will share the *same* memory model specs. I read that this is so, that in fact C11 is "inheriting" the C++11 memory model (for whatever historical reasons the latter happened either first or at the same time/with the same people, though I think Boehm, who's a C++ guy primarily, had a lot to say.) , but I'd like to make sure asking someone more knowledgeable.
2. My next question is: will GCC ever implement this memory model at all? I haven't seen the roadmap for this, and was wondering if someone had a "scoop".

Comment: as a comment since you didn't ask about that directly: I think the latest version of clang already implements these models.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Thanks, yes, I wanted to know about clang as well, but I thought I was pushing it, so I tried to focus the question.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Looks like no, it isn't yet implemented, at least according to http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Comment: @Dervin: It's important to note that when GCC or Clang says that they support something, they're generally serious about it (minus bugs of course). They won't say that they support it until they've been through their codebase and made reasonably sure that it conforms to the spec's corner cases. Microsoft, on the other hand, takes a much less rigorous approach to this sort of thing, outright claiming that ["there appears to be nothing for a compiler implementation to do"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx). Which is *preposterous*.

Comment: @DervinThunk, you asked for the *model*. It does it through the new builtins, please have a look at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#__c11_atomic . The syntactic sugar that has to be added around that is relatively minimal, so this will come soon.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Ah, I see what you mean. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. The memory model was developed for C++11, and adopted by C11. Lawrence Crowl did a lot of work to ensure that the interface for atomic operations was as close as possible. There were quite a few people involved, but you are right that Hans Boehm was one of them.
2. GCC currently (4.7) implements a reasonable approximation of the memory model. Certainly close enough that most programs won't be able tell the difference. I'm fairly sure that full conformance is on their plan, but don't know the timetable, as I'm not involved.